# Multiple index but single type elastic search spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement multiple indexes such as index1/type1 index2/type1 and so on.

When i try to define the class with the annotation @Document i need to specify the indexname.

Is there a way to just define the type and pass the index name as an argument while creating the index.

```
ElasticSearchTemplate.createIndex(Indexname, type.class) ?
```

Is something like this possible.